# Are there risks to encryption of Windows 7 external hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, encryption

For greater security, I want to encrypt my USB 3.0 external hard drives, to make it harder for Internet or LAN hacker to get at it; or if external hard disk physically stolen.

Encryption method would be:
1. Select all folders of external hard disk.
2. Right-click > General tab > Advanced button > Advanced Attributes window > select "Encrypt contents to secure data" > then OK.

The only risk I know is if Windows account password is lost.

From time to time, may need to disconnect external hard disk and plug to another computer, especially if computer eventually replaced.  Is this a risk?

Is there any risk to encryption of external hard disk that is compressed?

Computer is Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

Comment: You do understand that If the volume is mounted, then the volume has already been decrypted, so malicious files can read your files on any volume that has been mounted by the os and unlocked.  If you are going to use encryption, you can't lose the password, so don't lose it.  I am speaking of FDE not EFS.

Answer (score 1):

There is risk in just about everything we do.

The risks you face when encrypting an external hard drive are:

- being unable to decrypt the drive if you forget/lose the key
- being unable to decrypt the drive if the encryption requires that it is connected to the system in which it was originally connected or requires a specific application to decrypt the drive, which is only available on the system you originally encrypted the drive on
- someone being unable to read the drive, so they format the drive to use it for something else

If you weight these risks against the risk of not encrypting your drive, you will find the cost of the risks for encrypting are generally a lot less than the cost of not encrypting.

The question you should be asking yourself is, does your data need to be encrypted?  If yes, then encrypt it, regardless of the media it's on.

Comment: As mentioned by @CIA, the risk is that if *anything* goes wrong with encryption, the *whole drive* becomes unavailable. Might it  be preferable to encrypt only specific folders (using Windows encryption or third-party tool)? That might also simplify backup of the drive.